# Why when I go to the code of a generated interface it shows an older compiled version?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, yaml, maven-3

My generated interface from a.yaml file looks like this: [image]
When I try to go to the source code of the interface that I generated by clicking and pressing ctrl in Intellij Idea [image]

It shows me this code:
[image]

I tried to change the source from Project structure but no success at all

Comment: if you run `mvn clean compile`?

Comment: Try to set `Automatically download | Sources` under `Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Importing` and rebuild the project from scratch